# Angular 4: Error on local build of github project that was previously working

Tags: node.js, angular

So I have a project on github and I was trying to upgrade to Angular 5.. which at first seemed to have worked, but later I discovered weird bugs and wanted to just continue working with what was working in the last commit.. back to Angular 4.. but when I tried to build the project I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (232,41): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (233,41): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1252,41): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1253,41): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1972,55): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1976,54): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1986,55): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1991,57): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (2005,48): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (2088,22): ',' expected.)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (232,94): Generic type 'IDirectiveFactory<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (233,96): Generic type 'IDirectiveFactory<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1252,94): Generic type 'IDirectiveFactory<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1253,96): Generic type 'IDirectiveFactory<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1973,27): Generic type 'IDirective<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1973,48): Generic type 'IDirectiveLinkFn<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1987,15): Generic type 'IDirectiveLinkFn<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (1988,16): Generic type 'IDirectiveLinkFn<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (2002,19): Generic type 'IDirectiveLinkFn<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (2002,46): Generic type 'IDirectivePrePost<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (2006,19): Generic type 'IDirectiveCompileFn<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (2015,16): Generic type 'IDirectiveLinkFn<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (2015,43): Generic type 'IDirectivePrePost<TScope, IScope>' requires 2 type argument(s).)
    /Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts (2088,24): Type parameter name cannot be 'any')
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "TheOneUnion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && npm run server",
    "build": "webpack --progress --color",
    "build:aot": "webpack --env.aot --env.client & webpack --env.aot --env.server",
    "build:prod": "webpack --env.aot --env.client -p & webpack --env.aot --env.server",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "prebuild:aot": "npm run clean",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "server": "nodemon dist/server.js",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "watch:dev": "npm run server & npm run watch",
    "debug:server": "node-nightly --inspect --debug-brk dist/server.js & webpack --watch"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.3",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@types/mongodb": "2.2.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.6",
    "aws-sdk": "2.23.0",
    "base64url": "2.0.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "bluebird": "3.5.0",
    "body-parser": "1.17.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "compression": "1.6.2",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "css-loader": "0.25.0",
    "css-to-string-loader": "0.1.2",
    "debug": "2.6.8",
    "elasticsearch": "12.1.3",
    "evaporate": "2.0.9",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "global": "4.3.2",
    "gm": "1.23.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "html-metadata": "^1.6.3",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "js.clone": "0.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.3.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "log4js": "1.1.1",
    "methods": "1.1.2",
    "minilog": "3.1.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "mongoose": "4.11.4",
    "morgan": "1.8.1",
    "ng2-facebook-sdk": "2.3.1",
    "node-ffprobe": "1.2.2",
    "node-sass": "4.5.0",
    "nodemailer": "4.1.0",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "request": "2.80.0",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.2",
    "webfontloader": "1.6.27",
    "xhr2": "0.1.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.14",
    "@types/angular-material": "1.1.54",
    "@types/aws-sdk": "0.0.42",
    "@types/base64url": "2.0.3",
    "@types/bluebird": "3.5.3",
    "@types/body-parser": "0.0.34",
    "@types/compression": "0.0.33",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "1.3.30",
    "@types/elasticsearch": "5.0.12",
    "@types/evaporate": "0.0.18",
    "@types/express": "4.0.35",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "4.0.40",
    "@types/gm": "1.17.29",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.29.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.43",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.1",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "7.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.54",
    "@types/mime": "0.0.29",
    "@types/mongoose": "4.7.19",
    "@types/morgan": "1.7.32",
    "@types/node": "7.0.8",
    "@types/nodemailer": "1.3.32",
    "@types/request": "0.0.41",
    "@types/serve-static": "1.7.31",
    "@types/webfontloader": "1.6.28",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "node-loader": "0.6.0",
    "nodemon": "1.11.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "1.7.1",
    "typescript": "2.5.3",
    "webpack": "3.5.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.6.0"
  }
}
```

the other developers working on the project have confirmed that they can run the build on the same branch I am fine... so it has to be a problem locally.. I've tried everything. deleting it and recloning. cleaning caches.. deleted and reinstalled node and all global packages as well as even reinstalling macOS... and still the same error. If anyone has the slightest idea of what I can try I will be very thankful.

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: 2.5.3 in my package.json

Comment: it was at 2.2.1 and was working then, but I tried upgrading to see if it would resolve it, no luck

Comment: And that's your globally installed version as well?
Anyway, maybe try upgrading to v2.4.2?

Comment: I've tried with and without the tsc global package, but the thing is it works fine on my other developer's machine and he doesn't have typescript installed globally

Comment: I've added my package.json above

Comment: I think 2.5.3 is too high. I'd go with 2.4.2.

Comment: okay 2.4.2 returned a different error 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'

Comment: Upgrade RxJS to 5.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TypeScript 2.4.2 and RxJS 5.4.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The following worked for me: I've uninstalled typescript globally and from project folder (sudo npm uninstall -g typescript). Then installed typescript in project folder with --save-dev (sudo npm install --save-dev typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0').